# Redirecting http to https (iis 7)

Tags: windows-server-2008

Our server redirects http://ourdomain.com/anything to http://ourdomain.com

Is is possible to get it to redirect and retain the anything part?

ie.

http://ourdomain.com/cat/dog

to

https://ourdomain.com/cat/dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link.  It may help.

http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Comment: Great link!  Solves all my problems.